# VBA - Date Format "mm/dd/yyyy"

Tags: vba, excel, date

My excel file format for date is `Mar 30 2016 10:12:27:396AM` i want to change the format to `mm/dd/yyyy`. but i'm having an error on my code..

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

this is the line i got the error  `SecondDate = Trim(Sheet2.Range("B" & RowNo).Value)`

**Note**: The data from Column A and B are dates

My Code:

```
Dim Result, RowNo As Long
Dim FirstDate As Variant
Dim SecondDate As Variant

RowNo = 2

    FirstDate = Trim(Sheet2.Range("A" & RowNo).Value)
    SecondDate = Trim(Sheet2.Range("B" & RowNo).Value)
    FirstDate = Format(FirstDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    SecondDate = Format(SecondDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    Do Until Sheet2.Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""

    FirstDate = Sheet2.Cells(RowNo, 1)
    SecondDate = Sheet2.Cells(RowNo, 2)

        If DateDiff("d", FirstDate, SecondDate) >= 15 Then
        Sheet2.Cells(RowNo, 3) = "1"
        Sheet2.Cells(RowNo, 4) = "2"

    End If

   RowNo = RowNo + 1
   Loop
```

i do feel like im in the right path..am i missing something?

**Update**: My script will get the data from `Column A` and `Column B` and using the *DateDiff* function i will *subtract* both columns if the difference is <15 tag it from `Column C and D` as `1, 2`

**note:**

- i only subtract the days from both columns.. but is it possible to subtract both days and years?
- it's working if i use the format mm/dd/yyyy in the excel but if i use other format i got the error *mismatch*

**Updated 2**:

```
       Column A            | Column B                   | Column C
Mar 1  2016 10:12:27:396AM | Mar 30 2016 10:12:27:396AM |
Mar 1  2016 10:12:27:396AM | Mar 30 2016 10:12:27:396AM |
```

in my file this is the date format, if you try this as sample data it won't work maybe because VBA doesnt recognize this as dateformat?

Comment: `Trim(Sheet2.Range("A" & RowNo).Value)` and `Format(FirstDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")` return a string, not a date.

Comment: Still having an error if i hover the `SecondDate` i got a value of `SecondDate = 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: The DIM statement will set FirstDate as Variant and SecondDate as Date. The calculation of FirstDate is fine because it is variant. The calculation of SecondDate is wrong because you are assigning a String to a Date datatype.

Comment: @OldUgly so i need to separate secondDate and Dim it as a variant?

Comment: I need a better description of what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide a small example of input and expected output? (I say this because I see a number of things that may be wrong, or right - not sure what you are trying to do)

Comment: A proper DIM statement with multiple variables on the same line will look like this: `Dim i As Long, j As Long, s As String`

Comment: @OldUgly i updated my question, please additional info below *My Code*

Comment: VBa is so sensitive in Date Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will address what you are trying to do.

Test Input:

[image]

Test Output:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub DateStuff()
    Dim FirstDate As Range, SecondDate As Range
    Dim RowNo As Long

    Set FirstDate = Sheet4.Range("A1")
    Set SecondDate = Sheet4.Range("A2")

    FirstDate.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    SecondDate.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

    RowNo = 2
    Do Until Sheet4.Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""
        Set FirstDate = Sheet4.Cells(RowNo, 1)
        Set SecondDate = Sheet4.Cells(RowNo, 2)
        If IsDate(FirstDate.Value) And IsDate(SecondDate.Value) Then
            If DateDiff("d", FirstDate, SecondDate) >= 15 Then
                Sheet4.Cells(RowNo, 3) = 1
                Sheet4.Cells(RowNo, 4) = 2
            End If
        End If
        RowNo = RowNo + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Please spend a few minutes to understand this code:

- FirstDate and SecondDate are Range data types, not Date or Variant. The data in the cells they point to are Date or something else.
- When setting the format, it sets how it is displayed on the worksheet. It is not formatting a character string in VBA.
- Before making the DateDiff call, ensure both FirstDate and SecondDate really contain Date datatypes in the cells, this will prevent many errors.
- Operations on Date datatypes using Date functions are NOT dependent on formatting. They use the internal Date type. Formatting ONLY affects how a date is converted to a string and/or displayed on the worksheets.

You asked about checking year instead of day. There are built in VBA functions (e.g. Year, Month, etc.) that will help with this.

**As to your update to your question:**

I am not sure where you are getting your time codes from, but Excel does not recognize `:000` for milliseconds. It uses `.000`. See below ...

[image]

Comment: the way you explained it is seriously good! i tried to use the *breakpoint* in order to see what's happening in every line of code,

Comment: value of my date is like this `Mar 30 2016 10:12:27:396AM` it's working on those format but not on this one. :(

Comment: An example please. I don't know what "this one" is.

Comment: please see the update on my question below...  i'm quite confused with this one...

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Can you fix it at the source? If not, perhaps a macro to process all your timestamps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108992/discussion-between-oldugly-and-7a65726f).